# ETL (Extract Transform Load) versus stored procedure for processing fact table data

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, etl, database-performance

When processing Fact table, do people commonly use a Data Flow Task (in SSIS) as their ETL (Extract Transform Load), or do they use stored procedures to process data for fact table?

Is it common to use a Data Flow Task with vlookup task to filter data and to insert data into fact table? Or write a stored procedure with SQL queries to process data into fact table?

While processing using Data Flow task, SQL Server seems to load data into server memory and process its Vlookup and Filter tasks and process the data back by batch into SQL Server database.

On the other hand, processing using stored procedure where data is stay in SQL Server. Your feed back is appreciated. Thank you.